# Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm using requests in Python3 on Windows via Pycharm, and I'm receiving a "SSL module is not available" error.

I've spent hours trying to figure out what could be causing this. I've reinstalled Anaconda, and I am completely stuck. When running the following

```
def Earlybird(daycount):
    url = 'https://msft.com'
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response)
Earlybird()
```

I receive the error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='msft.com', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError("Can't 
connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

I have no idea what could be causing this. As Anaconda is a recent install, I would assume everything would be up-to-date, so I'm unsure if this is pointing to the wrong SSL ?

Comment: The instructions by jezdez here https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11795 helped me solve this. Had to do a clean install of miniconda, nothing else worked.

Answer (score 162):

Don't know if this has been solved yet but I was getting similar problems with Anaconda python 3.7.3 and Idle on Windows 10. Fixed it by adding:

```
<path>\Anaconda3
<path>\Anaconda3\scripts
<path>\Anaconda3\Library\bin
```

to the PATH variable.

Comment: Although don't know why we have to export multiple paths, but it works for me, thanks.

Comment: THIS WORKED FOR ME! not "execstack ..." cmd but this one! adding path/anaconda3/library/bin worked for me

Comment: Not sure to understand how/where do we have to add this 3 paths ?

Comment: Alex - add these items to the PATH environment variable (e.g see Mukesh Methaniya/Neuron answer below)

Comment: Where do I have to add these paths? I am trying to run a python code from specific folder using ```python get-pip.py```

Comment: Worked on `Anaconda Python 3.8.3` on a `Windows 10` server. Just had to alter  the local `path` environment variable.

Comment: This solution is much better than setting ssl_verify: false as suggested in other posts (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563757/conda-update-condahttperror-http-none). Apparently, that solution has security issues

Comment: It seems like my User variables only allow for one PATH, it keeps replacing my old PATH so I can't get all 3. Can Anyone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974818/how-to-add-multiple-paths-to-the-system-variable-in-environment-variables-in-win

This solved my problem: Use ; to separate each path.

Comment: I added these paths running `Edit the system environment variables` from Windows search box. Changes were picked up by new `Anaconda` prompt, but had to reboot for `PyCharm` to see the updated PATH.

Comment: Within your conda env folder (e.g., C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\MyCoolEnv)
Copy:   
libcrypto-1_1-x64.*
libssl-1_1-x64.*

From ".\Library\bin to .\DLLs

This works for my XAMPP cgi-bin test script running Python under my MyCoolEnv

Answer (score 92):

I am on Windows 10, I had the problem with a new fresh installation of Anaconda on python 3.7.4, this post on github solved my problem:

( source: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8273)

I cite:

"
My workaround:
I have copied the following files

```
libcrypto-1_1-x64.*
libssl-1_1-x64.*
```

from D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin to D:\Anaconda3\DLLs.

And it works as a charm!
"

Comment: Same versions of everything for me. Windows 10 Miniconda which had 3.7.4. Fixed with this solution.

Answer (score 25):

Windows Users need to set below paths:

- `..\Anaconda3`
- `..\Anaconda3\scripts`
- `..\Anaconda3\Library\bin`

**Per user:**

1. Open Environment variable
2. Click <kbd>User Variable</kbd>
3. Close command prompt if already open and reopen it

**System wide** (requires restart)**:**

1. Open Environment variable
2. Click <kbd>System Variable</kbd>
3. Restart Windows

Comment: Where do you set the path? Add "new" and then make a path for each of the Anaconda3 folders?

Answer (score 17):

I got it solved by installing OpenSSL according to the following recommendation: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8046#issuecomment-450515815

Corresponding ticket in the conda repository: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8046

**Update:** the problem (in PyCharm) should be solved in 2019.1 version (Early Access Preview build is already available https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/).

Answer (score 15):

I have faced it on 04/2020. These are the options that I tried and the last solution get me through.

**Problem:**

Requests module works fine when I use in Spyder IDE but when I try to execute the script in windows it fails with SSL error. It works fine for HTTP requests but for HTTPS requests i got SSL error.

1. I tired with Veify=True, False , also with Certs. **Same error**.
2. Removed Certifi - conda remove certifi - **Did not work**  Updated
3. openssl , certifi - **Still same error** ( Refer :
   https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/494)  Added
4. the path variables - **Same error**
5. Created new environment in
   Anaconda - **same error**

**Solution that fixed it:**

Solution from: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8273

I have copied the following files from Anaconda3\Library\bin to \Anaconda3\DLL

libcrypto-1_1-x64.*
libssl-1_1-x64.*

Comment: This worked for me too! Thanks for going through all the debugging steps :)

Comment: I added so many environment variables, installed the OpenSSL thingy, and nothing worked... Until I tried your last solution. :)))

Comment: This one is the only one that works for me as well.

Comment: I found this answer illiminating as it was a precursor to "Conda Upgrade Python"   I am using Miniconda.  The upgrade found incorrect versions to "DOWNGRADE" and missing packages.

Comment: yes! great fix. For those of us who don't particularly understand how it all works, this video walks you through it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQ9t93FnqZc

Answer (score 11):

this issue was driving me insane until i found this post which said to do

```
brew upgrade python3
```

(not using pycharm, using sublime)

[Error when importing ssl in Python 3.7.4 on macOS 10.14.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59433524/error-when-importing-ssl-in-python-3-7-4-on-macos-10-14-6)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same thing on my Windows 10 installation.

Anaconda3 would not open Anaconda Navigator before I copied `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and libssl-1_1-x64.dll` from `Anaconda3\Library\bin to \Anaconda3\DLL`.

Once I did that `pip` install in the base environment worked fine but not in another environment I created. I had to do the same as above in the new environment.

That is, copy `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and libssl-1_1-x64.dll` from `\<env folder>\Library\bin` to `\<env folder>\DLL` then it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you for sharing.  I was having issue above with one Python environment working and another experiencing the dreaded SSL error given above.  In my case I just replaced the libssl-1_1.dll library in the problem environment with the copy from the "working" environment and that fixed it in my case.

Answer (score 7):

After dealing with the same issue on Windows 10, the solution is fairly straightforward:

1. Open an Anaconda Prompt
2. Run `conda init`
3. Close and reopen any open Python interpreters (PyCharm, Anaconda Prompt, cmd, etc.) where you want to run your code

Run your code again and it should work. I had upgraded both Anaconda and PyCharm, and had the issue with all combinations of versions until I ran `conda init`, which adds to your PATH much like the answer from [Paul Stevens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55632553/1024735) . Don't skip #3—restarting PyCharm or any other interpreter is key.

Comment: Great thank you for this! VSCode just completed its monthly auto-update on my machine and all of a sudden this problem appeared and your solution worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't have Anaconda so the steps I took are:

- `brew uninstall python3`
- `brew install python3`

  - got an error message stating,`Your Xcode (10.2) is too outdated. Please update to Xcode 11.3 (or delete it). Xcode can be updated from the App Store.`**So, I deleted Xcode since no update would show, then I reinstalled it.
  - ran `xcode-select --install` after. If you don't.. you'll get an error: `The following formula python cannot be installed as binary package and must be built from source. Install the Command Line Tools: xcode-select --install`
- ran `brew install python3` and it completed successfully.

Used this script just to see if it works

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.office.com')
print(r)
```

Ran the script python3 and python3.7 and output was `<Response [200]>` instead of SSLError.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to add paths to environment if you use the **Anaconda Prompt.**

Start the Anaconda prompt change to your directory and run your script or start your editor from there. This will ensure you are in the full Anaconda environment and the SSL error will stop.

**Whats the difference between command prompt and Anaconda Prompt?**
See  this SO answer to [what is the difference between command prompt and anaconda prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37995670/461887).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem on Windows 10 using Conda and Python 2.7.2

After trying many, many solutions I came across [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53548593/1409983) which suggested that there is an issue with openssl in that build.

Once I downgraded python to 3.7.1 (build h33f27b4_4) everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

After spending a few hours going through the Anaconda documentation, Github issue tickets and so on, I finally managed to get it working on Windows 10 64-bit (Anaconda 3.7). The thing it worked for me was to install the Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.1d binary file from https://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL-1_1_1d.exe.

**NOTE**: The version seems to matter! I have tried the 1.1.0L (as suggested in other comments and responses) but with this version, the problem persisted. If you keep having problems after installing some OpenSSL libs, keep trying until you find the right version. For Anaconda 3.7 on Windows 10 it seems that the right one is the 1.1.1d. I did not try the light version.

Things that **did not work** for me:

- Following the Anaconda troubleshooting (https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#ssl-connection-errors). Activating the environment and doing what they say did not help at all.
- Changing `ssl_verify` option to `False`
- Installing Anaconda 3 with the option "Add to Path"
- Manually copying the `libcrypto` and `libssl` DLLs to a different location (see https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8273#issue-409800067)

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the same SSL error while doing a pip install after a fresh anaconda installation. What helped was activating the base environment before doing the pip install.
Do an `activate base` from cmd and then run your python script. You can also try `'conda run -n base python script.py'` Reference - https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8487

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue in my team mates machines. Fixed the same with adding anaconda path. In my system below is path of Anaconda:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

This errors happens in VSCode with Python 3.7.3 but works fine in IDLE editor in Windows 10 with Python 3.7.0.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you create the project with conda environment option selected.

My problem solved by recreate the project and select "conda" from "New environment using" options

see image:

[image: New environment setting]

Comment: Just needed to `Add Interpreter` then to choose `existing environnement` and it did the trick. No need to recreate the project.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the command is ran from within the virtual environment; that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in VS Code.

The solution was to launch VS Code using Anaconda Prompt.

That is, run Anaconda Prompt, activate your virtual environment if you're using one, and then enter `code [working directory]`.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also occur if you're accidentally using an Anaconda virtual environment that doesn't have the requests library downloaded, this was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

going to the website: gives me following information from developer tool and looking at headers. (right click --> inspect. then open network tab and check headers)

- Request URL: http://www.msft.com/
- Request Method: GET
- Status Code:200 OK
- Remote Address: 205.178.189.130:80
- Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

So we see we need to perform a request to HTTP, not HTTPS.

```
import requests


def Earlybird():
    url = 'http://msft.com/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Earlybird()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This issue was fixed on windows 10
I was facing same issue with  virtual environment on windows 10.
Issue was solved with running CMD as administrator and creating new virtual environment.

- Run cmd as administrator
- create virtual environment **(virtualenv .venv )**
- activate virtual environment **.venv\Scripts\activate**
- Pip install requests

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing the following in my windows 10:

```
mklink "C:\Users\hal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\DLLs\libssl-1_1-x64.dll" "C:\Users\hal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll"

mklink "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll" "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use VSCode to edit and debug and the only solution that worked for me was to edit the environment variables in windows..  Apparently this causes issues but I'm not sure what they are.

Running from the Anaconda prompt (as suggested by sayth) was NOT an option for me.  Or perhaps the suggestion was to run the anaconda prompt and the from the anaconda prompt somehow start VSCode.   Doesn't sound like a reasonable request.

This appears to be a long running chronic issue without a definitive global answer that works for everyone.

Comment: Not sure what "not a reasonable request" means, but it is actually generally good practice for avoiding weird errors, and it resolves this error too. It's not hard, just enter `code` in the prompt to launch VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 - this is a workaround and does not fix the root issue however, if you just need to install something and move on; Execute the following at the command prompt, powershell or dockerfile:

pip config set global.trusted_host "pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this error occurs because the path of anaconda hasnt been saved environment variables.
Solution::

- Punch "Edit environment variables" in your search box and select "Edit environment variables for your account"
- It opens a modal
- Click on the Path
- Then click "EDIT" underneath
- leave this open, and follow the remaining steps
- Punch Anaconda in your windows search box
- Open the file location
- Copy the first path you see
- Go back to the first modal you opened in Edit Variable account
- Click on "NEW" in this modal and paste the directory path you copied
- Go back to your anaconda directory
- Search for "SCRIPTS", ensure "PIP" is in this Scripts folder, Copy the "Scripts" directory path
- Go back to the "Edit environment variables" modal you opened
- Click "NEW" in this modal, and paste the SCRIPTS directory path you copied.
- Go back to the anaconda directory.
- This time exit away from the SCRIPTS directory by going back one step
- Look for "LIBRARY" in the anaconda directory
- Enter into LIBRARY and copy the path
- Go to the Edit Environment variables" modal you opened.
- Click on NEW, paste the LIBRARY path you copied.
- Now click okay on yhis modal. Click okay all through till it exits
- Then create a new virtual environment.
- Activate this virtual environment and try installing your libraries.

**OR WATCH** : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9AeWgZJTZA

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when trying to create a conda environment from an environment.yml file.  It simply turned out that I had to activate the base environment first:
D:\my_folder> conda activate base

Then the error went away:
(base) D:\my_folder> conda env create --file environment.yml