# Reticulate can't install python packages

Tags: python, r, reticulate, seurat

I'm trying to run the Seurat pipeline in RStudio (Windows 10 , which requires having the python library 'umap-learn' installed (Seurat walkthrough: https://satijalab.org/seurat/v3.0/pbmc3k_tutorial.html).

To install said library, I'm using the reticulate library in R in the following manner:

```
library(reticulate)
py_install(packages = 'umap-learn')
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in conda_python(envname = envname, conda = conda) : 
  conda environment r-reticulate not found
```

I've tried just about everything I can think of:

- Providing py_install with a path to python directly
- Uninstall / Reinstall of RStudio
- Uninstall / Reinstall of Anaconda
- Tried adding Anaconda to system path
- Using devtools version of Reticulate
- Using the use_python function: use_python("C://Users/lvlah/Anaconda3/python.exe")

At my wit's end with this - none of my colleagues have had this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and what seems to be an issue is that you need to first manually create the `r-reticulate` environment. I did it manually in Anaconda Navigator, but you can also do `conda_create("r-reticulate")` within R, as detailed in [this tutorial](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/python_packages.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and after finding [this helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135206/requests-caused-by-sslerrorcant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module) I've solved it by installing OpenSSL. Hope it works for you!

Comment: Tried that with no luck, thank you for the answer though.