# SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool python pandas-datareader

Tags: python, ssl, yahoo, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 19)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 22)
gs = web.DataReader("078930.KS", "yahoo", start, end)
```

it's a just simple code and it gives this kind of error

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
>   C:/Users/asdf/PycharmProjects/untitled1/asdf.py Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 588, in urlopen
>       conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 248, in _get_conn
>       return conn or self._new_conn()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 816, in _new_conn
>       raise SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL " urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the
>   SSL module is not available.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
>   line 449, in send
>       timeout=timeout   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 638, in urlopen
>       _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py",
>   line 398, in increment
>       raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url:
>   /quote/078930.KS/history?period1=1455822000&period2=1456167599&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module
>   is not available."))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/asdf/PycharmProjects/untitled1/asdf.py", line 5, in 
>       gs = web.DataReader("078930.KS", "yahoo", start, end)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py",
>   line 310, in DataReader
>       session=session).read()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py",
>   line 210, in read
>       params=self._get_params(self.symbols))   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py",
>   line 129, in _read_one_data
>       resp = self._get_response(url, params=params)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py",
>   line 132, in _get_response
>       headers=headers)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
>   line 546, in get
>       return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
>   line 533, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
>   line 646, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
>   line 514, in send
>       raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url:
>   /quote/078930.KS/history?period1=1455822000&period2=1456167599&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module
>   is not available."))
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I'm using 32bit anaconda version 3.7.3

Any Idea...what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Requests (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.") Error in PyCharm requesting website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135206/requests-caused-by-sslerrorcant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module)