# SSL sertificate problem while using pip in conda environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

**OC: MS Windows 10 Professional**

**conda: 4.7.11**

**pip: 19.2.2**

**python: 3.7.4**

**cuda: 10.1.168**

Need to install pycuda in isolated conda environment. I created new env as said in conda [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html):

```
conda create -n cudaenv
conda install -n cudaenv cudatoolkit
```

Then installed pip:

```
conda install -n cudaenv pip
conda activate cudaenv
```

And trying to install pycuda in it:

```
pip install pycuda-2019.1.2+cuda101-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

...then an error occured

```
(cudaenv) D:\Downloads>**pip install pycuda-2019.1.2+cuda101-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl**f
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Processing d:\downloads\pycuda-2019.1.2+cuda101-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting appdirs>=1.4.0 (from pycuda==2019.1.2+cuda101)
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/appdirs/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/appdirs/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/appdirs/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/appdirs/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/appdirs/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/appdirs/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/appdirs/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement appdirs>=1.4.0 (from pycuda==2019.1.2+cuda101) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for appdirs>=1.4.0 (from pycuda==2019.1.2+cuda101)
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

So, i got an SSL error despite the fact that i'm trying to install pycuda from wheel. More of that, flags `--trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org` does not help, I'v got ths same error.

From the base environment pip works properly. Can somebody say, what does it mean?

**upd:** looks like it trying to get appdirs from the remote repo, but fails due to ssl problems... `--trusted-host` still does not help. Pip's version is the latest.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135206/requests-caused-by-sslerrorcant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module

Comment: **I've installed the binaries from here: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html This site is mentioned on the official OpenSSL wiki. It solved my problem** It helped, thanks!