# Python3.7 SSL error on raspberry pi3 pipinstall problem

Tags: python, ssl

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

Comment: Please check if you have openssl installed on your Pi. Try sudo apt-get install openssl. Also, please use pip3 to install modules for python 3.7.

Comment: so yeah I do have ssl installed but its 1.0.1 which is outdated I guess? but how would I go about updating it?

Comment: Try running sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Requests (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.") Error in PyCharm requesting website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135206/requests-caused-by-sslerrorcant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module)

Comment: still gives the same SSL error after I do that, Yeah I ran what you said and it still didn't update the version its still on 1.0.1

Comment: also the fix you sent seems to be for windows 10 while this would be on a Linux OS

Comment: also just installed 3.8 same problem