# How to avoid SSL error with Anaconda + batch

Tags: python, batch-file, ssl, anaconda, telegram-bot

#### Actual Behavior

I have a script sending message to the Telegram Messenger API.

When I run it in Spyder, everything is ok.

When I use the batch created using "C:\Users\Alex\anaconda3\python.exe" as path in my txt file, I have the following errors (in Anaconda Prompt)

```
 "Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.

"requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot9[confidential url] (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))"
```

#### Expected Behavior

When I launch my script in SPyder, everything is ok : I receive the text I want to receive on my Instagram messenger account. I would like to be able to do the same with my batch file.

#### Steps to Reproduce

I have a script as follow : 
def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):

```
bot_token = 'token'
bot_chatID = '-id'
send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message
response = requests.get(send_text)

return response.json()

telegram_bot_sendtext("text")
```

I created the batch file using : 
"C:\Users\Alex\anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\U\project.py"
pause

Anaconda or Miniconda version:

Anaconda3 . 2020.02

Operating System:

I'm on Windows 10
 v1903

Comment: I would assume, you'd need to tell it where to find modules! Is the module to be found somewhere within `sys.path` / `PYTHONPATH`? If not what did you do to include/append it? You really haven't given us enough information or code upon which to base ideas or solutions.

Comment: My god it's refreshing to see such a well-written question. I don't have Anaconda3 installed so I can't test this, but based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55632553/4158862) that I see you already found, you should only have to add `set "path=%path%;%userprofile%\Anaconda3;%userprofile%\Anaconda3\scripts;%userprofile%\Anaconda3\Library\bin"` to the start of your batch script.

Comment: Refreshing perhaps @SomethingDark, but instead, what should have happened, is that they edited [their first attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61124477), and tried to have it reopened, not post it again with changes.