# SSLError while running python script from console

Tags: python, ssl, anaconda, conda

I have a problem with following script:

```
import requests

path = 'https://www.google.com/'

r = requests.get(path)

print(r.status_code)
```

When I am running this code in spyder IDE it is working properly.

When I am running it from console with commands:

```
activate my_env
python script.py
```

It is also working.

But when I am running it from console with command:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_env\python.exe script.py
```

It gives me error:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=44
>   3): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS
>    URL because the SSL module is not available."))

I was trying to add `proxies` param and certificate location to `verify` param, but nothing seems to help.

I am using python 3.7 and my working environment is Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Is Spyder using a different Python installation than the one in the Conda environment?

Comment: No, both in console and spyder I was using the same conda env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60551653/10536858), I can't believe I haven't seen it before.

In short, copy files `libcrypto-1_1-x64.*`, `libssl-1_1-x64.*` from D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin to D:\Anaconda3\DLLs.