# Requests (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.") On Linux

Tags: python, linux, ssl, python-requests, anaconda

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135206/requests-caused-by-sslerrorcant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module) but for Windows users. I am getting this error on a Linux machine on a 3rd party application under a Anaconda environment. I added the following paths to my `PATH` env:

```
<path>/anaconda2/lib
<path>/anaconda2/bin
```

But when I run:

```
import requests
requests.get("https://api.ipify.org")
```

I get the error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ipify.org', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError("Can't 
connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

The 3rd party application and a conda shell both include those paths in the `PATH` env but it only works on the shell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Requests (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.") Error in PyCharm requesting website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135206/requests-caused-by-sslerrorcant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module)

Comment: That is the question I linked, but it is for windows users. It was a problem with the 3rd party app libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says "SSL module is not available". Requests uses `openssl` for its "SSL module" so make sure `openssl` is installed and working correctly.

First run:

```
~$ conda list
```

You should see `openssl` and `pyopenssl` in the output

if you don't install `openssl` and `pyopenssl`

If openssl is installed run:

```
~$ openssl
```

If you get:

```
openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument
```

Run using the version number from above

```
~$ sudo find / -name libcrypto.so.[your version]
```

Then using the path to libcrypto.so.[your version] from the output of the above:

```
~$ sudo execstack -c [path to]/libcrypto.so.[your version]
```

Then run to test:

```
~$ openssl
OpenSSL>
```

You will need to do this for all environments

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the `_ssl.so` module in the `lib-dynload` directory of my python environment was being overriden by the `_ssl.so` module in the 3rd party software, it was conflicting. So I have made a sym-link to my own module.