# Running Script from Command Line vs. Anaconda/Spyder/Jupyter environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I have a script that connects to the TD Ameritrade API (I have a developer account and a margin account).

I created a script to pull some information from there and it works perfectly when I run from Jupyter or Spyder, but when I try to run from command line, I get the below error:

`(Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))`

What is causing this to happen?

Is it possible to automate scripts within Jupyter itself?

I am running from the command line because I would like to put the script on a schedule and as far as I know I would have to test my code from command line before setting it to run automatically.

Comment: this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135206/requests-caused-by-sslerrorcant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module

Comment: Solution provided in that link. Thank you Mr. Leon