# SSLError on simple, public API call

Tags: python, api, ssl, python-requests, anaconda

So I'm trying to make a simple API call using the 'requests' library within python. Running into a module unavailable traceback error that I can't seem to resolve from looking at other forums on this same subject.

I'm running the below script and reviewing the terminal window in my MS vis studio IDE.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.fema.gov/api/open/v2/DisasterDeclarationsSummaries')

status = r.status_code

print(r)
print(status)
```

Very basic, yes. The ultimate error I'm seeing is:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.fema.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/open/v2/DisasterDeclarationsSummaries (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

I'm running python for the first time on a windows machine and via Anaconda. I've attempted twice to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda and no luck. My work peers that have (what should be) identical laptop configurations can run the code just fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135206/requests-caused-by-sslerrorcant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module

Comment: try to make request via http instead https

Comment: @MaxYarmolinsky yea I saw that post. Can't add anything to my PATH according to my IT department.

Comment: @loliallen same traceback error when I adjust to HTTP :/